# Explode nested list of objects into DataFrame in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-spark

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
|               Column                           |
|------------------------------------------------|
|[{a: 2, b: 4}, {a: 2, b: 3}]                    |
|------------------------------------------------|
|[{a: 12, b: 14}, {a: 25, b: 33}, {a: 22, b: 31}]|
...
```

And I need to convert it to dataframe like

```
| a | b |
|---|---|
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 |
|12 |13 |
```

Comment: What's the type of your original DF? Is it JSON or you meant to represent a custom type of yours and these are sequence of some case classes?

Comment: Yeah it's a sequence of instances of a class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest approach might be to use SparkSQL function [`inline`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/sql/index.html#inline) as shown below:

```
case class AB(a: Int, b: Int)

val df = Seq(
    Seq(AB(2, 4), AB(2,3)),
    Seq(AB(12, 14), AB(25, 33), AB(22, 31))
  ).toDF("arrAB")

df.select(inline($"arrAB")).show
/*
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  2|  4|
|  2|  3|
| 12| 14|
| 25| 33|
| 22| 31|
+---+---+
*/
```

Note that while `inline` has been part of the SparkSQL API since `2.0`, it's available as a built-in function for Dataframes only on `Spark 3.4+`.  To use it on older Spark versions, wrap it with [`expr`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#expr(expr:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) like below:

```
df.select(expr("inline(arrAB)"))
```

Comment: Looks great but I was unable to make it work (I'm pretty new to Spark maybe this is the reason) but I couldn't find where to import the `inline` function from.

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html

Comment: @vZ10, please see my expanded answer.